# In xcode, how do I select the first suggested item from the drop-down?

Tags: xcode

See picture for the suggested item list that I am talking about. When that comes up, I can press tab and it will write the first word of the first suggested item, but it is annoying to continuously press tab to select the first variable if there are a lot of words in it.

Is there one hotkey combination I can get to select the entire first item?

[The suggestion list I am referring to](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oCvLr.png)